# Magento 2 module not working on live

Tags: magento2, module, staging

I created a **`custom module`** but it doesn’t work on **live**. On **staging** it works fine.
The module is **`installed`** and **`enabled`**.
I also checked **`config.php`** and **`setup_module table`**, **`run bin/magento module:status`** and the module is there.

> Does anyone know what might be the reason for this?

Comment: is the cache cleaned?

Comment: yes the cache is cleaned

Comment: You can check in admin if your module have option in admin configuration YES and NO And this option should be Yes as per your store.

Comment: There is nothing like that, I created the module :D